# Scroll down to a specific View in React Native ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I want to be able to scroll a  after pressing button so that it visible on screen. How can I tell a react-native ScrollView move to a certain?

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can use the property scrollTo like below

```
import {useRef} from "react"
import {
  ScrollView,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

const YouComp = () => {
  const refScrollView = useRef(null);
  const moveTo = () => {
    refScrollView.current.scrollTo({x: value1, y: value2});
    // or just refScrollView.current.scrollTo({x: value1}); if you want to scroll horizontally
    // or just refScrollView.current.scrollTo({y: value2}); if you want to scroll vertically
  }

  return (<>
  <Button onPress={moveTo} title="title" />
  <ScrollView ref={refScrollView}>
    ...
  </ScrollView>
  </>);
}
```

You can set whether x or y value or both

Check the full doc [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create reference to element

```
this.scrollViewRefName = React.createRef()
```

Then pass it to ref attribute

```
<ScrollView ref={this.scrollViewRefName}>
```

Then you trigger the function from your button with `scrollToTheEnd` or wherever you want to scroll within the element

```
<View style={styles.ButtonContainer}>
  <Button onPress={() => { this.scrollViewRef.current.scrollToTheEnd }} />
</View>
```

Note that you may need extra callback function in onPress depending on from which context you have the components

Answer (score 0):

using ref and `scrollTo` is just bullshit and dose not always work.

Here is how i did it.

```js
const [scrollYPosition, setScrollYPosition] = useState(0);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const goToItem = () => {

    // lets go to item 200

    // the 200 is the item position and the 150 is the item height.
    setScrollYPosition(200 * 150);

  }

  <ScrollView contentOffset = {
    {
      y: scrollYPosition,
      x: 0
    }
  }>
  // papulate your data and lets say that each item has 150 in height
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text, Button, findNodeHandle, UIManager } from 'react-native';

const ScrollToSpecificView = () => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToView = () => {
    const targetViewRef = /* Ref of the target view */;
    
    if (targetViewRef.current) {
      // Find the target view's node handle
      const targetViewNodeHandle = findNodeHandle(targetViewRef.current);

      // Use measureLayout to get the position of the target view
      UIManager.measureLayout(
        targetViewNodeHandle,
        scrollViewRef.current.getInnerViewNode(),
        () => {},
        (x, y) => {
          // Scroll to the position of the target view
          scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y, animated: true });
        }
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
        {/* Your scrollable content goes here */}
        <Text ref={/* Ref of the target view */}>View 1</Text>
        <Text>View 2</Text>
        <Text>View 3</Text>
        {/* ... more content ... */}
      </ScrollView>

      {/* Button to trigger scroll to specific view */}
      <Button title="Scroll to View 1" onPress={scrollToView} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ScrollToSpecificView;
```

Answer (score 0):

const scrollToSpecificView = (myRef: any) => {

```
    if (myRef) {//ref of target view
     // Use measureLayout to get the position of targeted view
     myRef.measureLayout(
        scrollViewRef.current.getInnerViewNode(),
        (x: number, y: number) => {
            // Scroll to the position of the ref
            scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y, animated: true });
        }
    );

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library
react-native-scroll-into-view